# All Reviews on Category Pages Not Present

Tags: magento

In my Magento install only one product shows reviews on the category page. Other products have reviews and the reviews are visible on the product page, but they don’t appear on the category page. I tried switching to the default theme and the behavior is the same. I also tried refreshing my cache, indexes, and even running cron.php, but that didn’t help.

Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

The culprit can be seen here:
http://miacotone.com/index.php/handbag-dust-covers.html

Notice the one review showing, but other products such as the Non-Woven Drawstring Handbag Dustcover also have reviews, but they don't appear on the category page.

Thanks for looking =)

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache/re-indexing?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from 1.6.0 to 1.6.1 seemed to resolve this issue for me.